# Electron-builder - Building Windows app on ubuntu, Docker command return : docker: invalid reference format error

Tags: docker, electron

Getting **docker: invalid reference format** error when i try to run this command on my electron project folder.

Here is the command:

```
docker run --rm -ti \
 --env-file <(env | grep -iE 'DEBUG|NODE_|ELECTRON_|YARN_|NPM_|CI|CIRCLE|TRAVIS_TAG|TRAVIS|TRAVIS_REPO_|TRAVIS_BUILD_|TRAVIS_BRANCH|TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_|APPVEYOR_|CSC_|GH_|GITHUB_|BT_|AWS_|STRIP|BUILD_') \
 --env ELECTRON_CACHE="/root/.cache/electron" \
 --env ELECTRON_BUILDER_CACHE="/root/.cache/electron-builder" \
 -v ${PWD}:/project \
 -v ${PWD##*/}-node-modules:/project/node_modules \
 -v ~/.cache/electron:/root/.cache/electron \
 -v ~/.cache/electron-builder:/root/.cache/electron-builder \
 electronuserland/builder:wine
```

Please how can i fix it?

Comment: There seem to be some complicated shell expansions in there.  If you put the word `echo` at the front of the line, it will just print out what the shell expands it to; is there anything there with unexpected spaces or punctuation?

Comment: Thank you David for your comment !

Comment: I added the word echos at the beginning and it brought me back to that : `docker run --rm -ti --env-file /dev/fd/63 --env ELECTRON_CACHE=/root/.cache/electron --env ELECTRON_BUILDER_CACHE=/root/.cache/electron-builder -v /home/afrikatik/Desktop development/mazegame_electron:/project -v mazegame_electron-node-modules:/project/node_modules -v /home/afrikatik/.cache/electron:/root/.cache/electron -v /home/afrikatik/.cache/electron-builder:/root/.cache/electron-builder electronuserland/builder:wine`

Comment: but after running it it gives me another error : **docker: open /dev/fd/63: no such file or directory**

Comment: If your current directory name `Desktop development` has a space in it, you _must_ enclose every reference to the directory name `${PWD}` in double quotes; `-v "${PWD}:/project"`.  If you don't, the shell will split this into two words as part of its expansion, and Docker interprets the second word `development/mazegame_electron:/project` as the image name.  (Also consider whether you can build your application code into an image instead of bind-mounting it from the host.)

Comment: Yes, my current directory as space in it `Desktop development`, I changed it to `Desktop_development` but the **docker: open /dev/fd/63: no such file or directory** error persist.(I had never used docker before, I just want to create an .exe file to distribute my project as ubuntu user, and the guy who explains it on youtube uses docker for that...
I dont know how to build application code into an image, but I will document myself on that)

Comment: The Electron documentation has a whole chapter on [Application Distribution](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-distribution) which might be a good read.  I don't think Docker is going to be a good match for you here: running a GUI application under Docker requires having Docker installed, requires administrator permissions to run at all, can't access normal user preferences, and is hard to do on native Linux and all but impossible on other host OSes.